# After [UIApplication performFetchWithCompletionHandler], what will happen to my App?

Tags: ios, background

just wondering what will happen after performFetchWithCompletionHandler, will my app stay in the memory, or will it get purged immediately? I've googled but no one seems to be caring about this.

Comment: based on your app usage, when you app is in background it will be given time to do some work. time slice would be of almost 30 seconds

Comment: i know that i have 30seconds, but i would like to know more about what happen once application performbackgroundfetch is returned

Comment: I think it depends on what the user is doing with the device - if it is otherwise idle then your app may remain idle but in memory. If they load a memory intensive app then it may be unloaded. You need to code on the assumption that your app is terminated after your message hod calls the completion handler and returns

Comment: So is just like regular life cycle? Paul could you please make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

> When this method is called, your app has up to 30 seconds of wall-clock time to perform the download operation and call the specified completion handler block. In practice, your app should call the completion handler block as soon as possible after downloading the needed data. If you do not call the completion handler in time, your app is terminated. More importantly, the system uses the elapsed time to calculate power usage and data costs for your app’s background downloads. If your app takes a long time to call the completion handler, it may be given fewer future opportunities to fetch data in the future.

Straight from Apple documentation - [UIApplication Delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:)